# App internationalization / localization (Flutter)

Tags: localization, translation

I am building a flutter app and want to localize my app. I am following the recommended method. I have implemented the method successfully and there is no error.

The problem is I dont know many of the languages I want this app to have. Can you please suggest a good solution? Do I hire people to translate it or is there any free way?

Any suggestion is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should start with googling something like “10 most spread languages” and consider them for starters.